# Which .NET runtime is my .NET assembly running in COM+ using?

Tags: .net, com+

Does anyone know how to tell which .NET runtime a .NET assembly running in COM+ is using?

We're expecting it to be using .NET1.1 but we also have .NET2 installed on the machine and need to know which version it is really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Process Explorer from Sysinternals to show the loaded assemblies for each process.

It's a free tool that every windows power user should use instead of the task manager.

Enable the lower pane and select the process running your code.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062

Comment: One of the Process Explorer menu bar icons shows you which assemblies are loaded. We used the version of the System assemblies to figure out which version of .NET we were using.